# APIv2 GitHub NetworkCommit Login empty

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to use GitHub's API through the library "github-java-sdk". 
I want to identify the lastest 100 committers of one repository.

For instance, when I run this command to analyse return data : http://github.com/tinoucas/dwm-tinou/network_data_chunk?748b1c901dc01fd14c4f8a1f8985525612683295

I noticed that some commits don't have the field "login" assigned. 
Could you tell me why it's empty ? 
How I could identify one committer who hasn't the login property assigned ?

Answer (score 0):

After having cloned this repository, printing out the header of one of the suspicious commit, one would notice within the **Author** and **Committer** fields a very weird email information.

```
$ git show 7c3efbad3d540d34726340bf727889d87b5376e4 --format=raw
commit 7c3efbad3d540d34726340bf727889d87b5376e4
tree a99909e793befcccb9f8b9f5aff3a789148ee9da
parent c4e62ae697937477a1b847e5a9a4caa906d0b130
author tinou <tinou@polter.(none)> 1234738874 +0100
committer tinou <tinou@polter.(none)> 1234738874 +0100
```

Comparing this to the information contained in the parent commit, the email is different

```
$ git show c4e62ae697937477a1b847e5a9a4caa906d0b130 --format=raw
commit c4e62ae697937477a1b847e5a9a4caa906d0b130
tree 61679418f1fe1acfe53440cb91092bb16f64c14a
parent e0bb39e6de991417ea2c55ebea17378d58480476
author tinou <tinoucas@gmail.com> 1231278215 +0100
committer tinou <tinoucas@gmail.com> 1231278215 +0100
```

If we use the GitHub web interface to display those two commits

- [The first one](https://github.com/tinoucas/dwm-tinou/commit/7c3efbad3d540d34726340bf727889d87b5376e4) displays a plain "tinou" as author
- [The second one](https://github.com/tinoucas/dwm-tinou/commit/c4e62ae697937477a1b847e5a9a4caa906d0b130) displays an enhanced clickable ["tinoucas"](https://github.com/tinoucas) author information along with its gravatar

My guess would be that GitHub uses the email address from the commits to retrieve the matching GitHub login. When the email address is obfuscated or can't be matched, no **login** information can be sent out through the API.